# how to hide or remove checkbox column by default on tree view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

When creating a tree view by default, one more column appears with a checkbox

[image: Something like thate]

how to hide or remove this column?

I will appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector is added in list renderer [_renderSelector](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js#L613) function, which is called when rendering the [header](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js#L511) or a [row](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js#L585).
Odoo checks if the list renderer `hasSelectors` attribute is set to true to add the selector (checkbox). To disable the selector, you will need to set `hasSelectors` to `false` when initializing the widget.

You can easily override the init function to be able to deactivate the selector by passing a value in the action context.

The following example alters the init function of the form render to check if `hasSelectors` attribute is present in state context and its value is set to `false`:

```
var ListRenderer = require('web.ListRenderer');
ListRenderer.include({
    init: function (parent, state, params) {
        this._super(parent, state, params);
        if ('hasSelectors' in state.context && !state.context.hasSelectors)
            this.hasSelectors = false;
    },
});
```

Using the above example, you can disable the selectors in any tree view just by setting the value of `hasSelectors` to `False` in context.

Answer (score 1):

In v14, you can use "flags: {'hasSelectors': False}" when you call the action view from a python function. You can also use flags such as 'withControlPanel': False if you want to remove the Action button and Search bar.

```
def view_tree(self):  
    return {
        'name': "My List View",
        'res_model': 'your.model',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'target': 'current',                        
        'domain': [],
        'flags': {'hasSelectors': False},
        'context': {},                        
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    }
```

Comment: hi, I use it when want call action to show treeview in python file  and it 's worked can you tell me how can I use this attribute in xml file while I defining a tree view as a default attribute ????