# How to hide record selector column of checkboxes in tree view odoo 16.0

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-16

I want to hide record selector or checkboxes column in tree view, the actions must be performed one for each record.

Or how to hide delete action from tree view, alternatively.

[Previous version: how to hide or remove checkbox column by default on tree view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529721/how-to-hide-or-remove-checkbox-column-by-default-on-tree-view)

[image: Items to hide]

I know that is a bad idea but i tray to hide column using backend css, but this hide column in all models

```css
.o_list_record_selector {
    display: none;
}
```

Tree view

```xml
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="cetiia_registro.list">
            <field name="name">list</field>
            <field name="model">cetiia_registro.registro</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree>
                    <field name="id" />
                    <field name="email" />
                    <field name="website_name" />
                    <field name="website_url" widget="url" options="{'target': 'new'}"
                        string="Website URL" />
                    <button string="Editar" type="object" name="action_open_edit_form" />
                    <button string="Ver sitio" type="object" name="action_view_website" />
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can easily create a new list view that disables selectors and set the `js_class` attribute in the tree view tag

   ***Example:***

   ```js
   /** @odoo-module **/
   import { registry } from '@web/core/registry';
   import { ListRenderer } from "@web/views/list/list_renderer";
   import { listView } from "@web/views/list/list_view";

   export class ListRendererNoSelectors extends ListRenderer {
       setup() {
           super.setup();
           this.props.allowSelectors = false;
       }
   };

   registry.category('views').add('no_selector_tree', {
       ...listView,
       Renderer: ListRendererNoSelectors,
   });
   ```

2. To hide the delete action, you just need to remove the delete access (Access Rights)